# Scaling Azure Computer Vision Service

Tags: azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am experimenting with the Azure Computer Vision service and it is working well.

The only issue is that I want to be able to process 6,000 files relatively quick.
Now Azure imposes a 10-Transaction Per Second limit which is fine, but how can I scale the service?

I was thinking of spinning up multiple instances, but it seems like an ugly way to solve this issue.

Please let me know the best way to tackle this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please contact [Azure support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request#create-a-support-request) for scaling your Azure Computer Vision resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly ask the support to have an upper limitation.

Submit a support request from Azure for that:

[image: Support button]

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for you response. I have submitted a ticket and am waiting to hear back. I just curious if there was a way to work with the 10 transactions per second limit. I have contacted support!

Comment: I’ve been in the same situation for face API a moment ago and the only clean solution I found was this one